# Defer a lambda in C++23

Tags: c++, raii, c++23

I like using the latest C++ for personal projects. I was wondering how I can defer lambdas (or use a scopeguard) in the latest C++

Below is a quick implementation. I like style 3 the best. Does the standard have anything like the below? Do I have any extremely obvious bugs with this? I only spent a few minutes writing this

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class DeferLambda {
    T l;
public:
    DeferLambda(T l) : l(l) { }
    ~DeferLambda() { l(); }
};

auto make_defer(auto p) -> DeferLambda<decltype(p)> { return {p}; }

#define NAME2(A, B) A ## B
#define NAME(A, B) NAME2(A, B)
#define L(X) auto NAME(defer, __LINE__) = make_defer(X);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DeferLambda a([]{puts("Style 1");});
    auto b = make_defer([]{puts("Style 2");});
    L([]{puts("Style 3");});
    puts("test");
}
```

Comment: Similar to Boost [ScopeExit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit)

Comment: Another (more verbose) possibility is to use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053351/how-do-i-use-a-custom-deleter-with-a-stdunique-ptr-member/19053630#19053630

Comment: This is how I've always done it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50182372/5869304 . The syntax for using it is simple and it doesn't require macros or `unique_ptr` with custom-deleters, just move semantics.  It also gives you the ability to cancel the execution or make it happen before end of scope.

Comment: at least two issues with this code: 1. It encourages users to squish lambdas into `make_defer` invocation instead of providing a properly named invokable entity. 2. Invokable entity will be invoked at destructor and therefore if it throws then program will be terminated. So it would be a good idea to check at compile time that invocation is `noexcept`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the standard have anything like the below?

Not as a built-in language feature, so creating a class and adding a user-defined destructor to it like you've done is how it has to be done. There are many variations on that theme, like [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit), which is not in the standard library, but has been proposed to be included.

> Do I have any extremely obvious bugs with this?

It depends on what you're after. If this is to be used as some kind of "finally" at the end of scopes, then you may want to `delete` the ability to *copy* your `DeferLambda`s. Otherwise, someone may end up with two of these things, doing the same operation when they go out of scope.