How to ensure that a given action is reverted before leaving the function?
Here's the context. I'm working on a Qt application that draws stuff. At some point, the logic may require to perform a rotation or a translation of the scene in order to draw specific objects, given that this rotation and/or translation should necessarily be reset before drawing other objects.
Recently, I found a bug where the objects weren't drawn correctly. I ended up by finding the cause, in the piece of code which looks like this:
void example(const QString &text) {
    ...  // A few lines of code.

    this->setRotation(angle);

    ...  // A few lines of code.

    if (text.trimmed().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    ...  // A few more lines of code.

    this->resetRotation();
}

The error was that I forgot to call resetRotation before the return in the if block.
What would be an idiomatic way, in modern C++, to prevent such cases from happening?
RAII-like pattern comes into mind, and I could imagine for setRotation to return an object which would automatically call resetRotation in its destructor—just like std::unique_ptr does with the pointer it holds. This, however, doesn't seem particularly clear from the perspective of the caller of setRotation. One may be forced to create a variable to store the actual result of setRotation if [[nodiscard]] attribute is used, but having a variable which has no other purpose than the cleanup (and which won't be called) would, I suppose, look weird.
Does it?
What are the alternatives?

This is exactly what RAII is for. So, yes, a little RAII wrapper will do exactly what you want. If it helps, you can consider (temporarily) setting the rotation as acquiring a resource which must be released.

Basically you want something like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit

The "original" way is to write a class whose destructor performs the action, but that involves quite a lot of boilerplate.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182244/simple-way-to-execute-code-at-the-end-of-function-scope for a range of terser options .  In my own projects I make up a class that is similar in functionality to the suggested experimental/scope_exit

std::experimental::scope_exit is broken. Check out https://ricab.github.io/scope_guard/ instead.

Don't make the return of the function the RAII object, just create the scope guard the line after it, and if you don't need the fancy scope guards features, you can write in 8 lines a simple scope guard that produces little codegen, almost identical to actually writing the function on each return path.

Sidenote: The requirement to have a set+reset pair often indicates that the property being modified does not actually belong where it currently is. Consider to pass it along as argument in the call chain, to make adjustments, modify a copy; then the "resetting" happens automatically (by throwing away the copy).

Instead of changing the semantics of resetRotation which might surprise some users, you can add an RAII wrapper which makes it very clear.
Something like:
template <typename T>
class AutoRotationReseter {
public:
    AutoRotationReseter(T& obj, double angle) : m_obj(obj) {
        m_obj.setRotation(angle);
    }

    ~AutoRotationReseter() {
        m_obj.resetRotation();
    }

    // Disable copy/move/assignment:
    AutoRotationReseter(AutoRotationReseter const &) = delete;
    AutoRotationReseter(AutoRotationReseter &&) = delete;
    AutoRotationReseter& operator=(AutoRotationReseter const &) = delete;
    AutoRotationReseter& operator=(AutoRotationReseter &&) = delete;

private:
    T & m_obj;
};

And then use it like e.g. this (following the code you posted):
{
    AutoRotationReseter reseter(*this, angle);
    // ...
} // scope ends => AutoRotationReseter will reset rotation

Live demo
Notes:

In order to respect the rule of 0/3/5 the copy/move/assignment operators are deleted (using them does not fit such a RAII warpper anyway).

I wrote it as a template to be more generic and also because I did not know your actual class.
If you need it for a specific class only, you can drop the template and simply replace T with your actual class.



As for any RAII object, handle rule of 3/5: for specific case, =delete copy/assignment does the job.

@Jarod42 good point - updated.
